# Custom editor templates not being called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, mvc-editor-templates

I have an MVC application using a number EditorTemplates and targetting .NET Framework 4.6.1.  I have one that I want to use to render an Enum as a set of radio buttons my users can choose from.

In my ViewModel, I have the following:

```
public enum ApplicationType { Register, Replace, Renew }

[UIHint("EnumRadioButtons")]
public ApplicationType AppType { get; set; }
```

On my view, I'm using

```
@Html.EditorForModel(Model)
```

And my editor template looks something like:

```
@model Enum

var listItems = Enum.GetValues(Model.GetType()).OfType<Enum>().Select( e => 
  new SelectListIten()
  {
    Text = getDescription(e), //Function just used to get the Display Value
    Value = e.ToString(),
    Selected = e.Equals(Model)
  });
foreach (var li in listItems)
{
  //Render the Radio Button
}
```

I also have another Enum editortemplate which renders my Enums into a dropdown list.  When rendering the EditorModel for my Model, the standard Enum editor template is used rather than my custom EnumRadioButtons template.  Any ideas?

I've also used the `[DataType("EnumRadioButtons")]` decoration to no avail.

This worked before when I've used this exact method and specific editor templates but targeting 4.0 of the .NET Framework.

Thanks

Simon

Comment: If I change my editor template to ```@model ApplicationType```, rename the template to be called ```ApplicationType``` and remove the ```UIHint``` attribiute, it will fire the correct editor template but I want a generic version that will work for any ```enum``` I want to display as as radio buttons.

Comment: Just to check... Your view file name is EnumRadioButtons.cshtml" and placed in Views/Shared/EditorTemplates right?

Comment: Hi Jon - yes, that's right